# How to add a Button (like 'Clear History') below the expanded SearchView (showing 10 recent searches) in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view

Can anyone please help in how to add a button to the expanded SearchView (placed in ActionBar) below the list of recent search suggestions the SearchView is showing?

Since SearchView extends LinearLayout, I have tried to add a button in the layout, but I am not able to place it below the expanded suggestions list.

I made a vertical linearlayout called 'mysearch' with a SearchView and a button below it. Then I also referred to it in `android:actionLayout="@layout/mysearch" in`menu.xml` for ActionBar.

I try to get a reference to SearchView in `onCreateOptionsMenu` of my activity by using

```
  SearchView searchView = 
      (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
```

When I run it, I get a `ClassCastException:cannot convert LinearLayout to SearchView`, maybe because `getActionView()` is expecting SearchView but here a LinearLayout it being returned. I dont know how to work around this.

Comment: is it possible for you to let us know about your final solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to put a `SearchView` into a vertical `LinearLayout` and simply add the button below it.

Comment: I tried to do that and use a layout in actionLayout attribute , but still not able to do it. I have put the details in the rephrased question above.Please help